# Scheduled Task runs After Wakeup from Sleep

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task at 1:00 every day to put my PC to sleep (using psshutdown.exe ... c:\windows\psshutdown.exe -d -t 30). Everythink works OK, but if I manually put the PC in sleep mode (running this command or pressing "Sleep" in Start Menu) when the PC wake up it "remember" that scheduled task has not run and then run the scheduled task ... It's like the PC "thinks" "***... Ohh I have to run the scheduled task at 1:00 and at this time I was sleeping ... It doesn't matter! I will run it now !!***"
Any idea about this issue ???

Answer (score 1):

This is default behavior.

When your computer is suspended (sleeping) it can't process any commands, so the scheduled task is not executed.

When you configure a scheduled task, on the settings tab, there's a checkbox saying: *Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed.*

Disable this checkbox and all is solved.

Answer (score -1):

In your scheduled task at 1:00, uncheck "wake up the computer to run this task" in Conditions tab. Because you don't need it to start running if the computer is already asleep.